# Microsoft Graph API with MSA Personal Account

Tags: asp.net, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using Microsoft Graph API to update the Outlook calendar in ASP.Net Application. I was using the Office 365 Business Account and it was working fine.
But when I use the Office 365 Personal Account **___@hotmail.com**, it is showing error:

> MsalClientException: ROPC does not support MSA accounts. See
> https://aka.ms/msal-net-ropc for details

. The screenshot is attached.
[image]
[image]

**Is there a way to use Office 365 Personal @hotmail account for this purpose? As I have subscription for my personal account.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us , this is expected behavior because ROPC does not support MSA personal accounts.

[image]

for more please see doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.msalerror.ropcdoesnotsupportmsaaccounts?view=azure-dotnet

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to use Microsoft Personal Account for Graph API operations?

Comment: you can try by changing the {tenant id} as "common", when you want to sign in your personal Account.